# Unit tests примеры

Tags: юнит-тесты

Для себя решила написать пару юнит тестов, чтобы знать что это такое. Google test. Написала, но я хз, правильно, не правильно они работают. Нигде ошибку не выдает. Посмотрите и скажите правильно ли я сделала. и наведите пример как  нужно если не правильно.

Я делала проверку стандартных функций

```
TEST(FindTest, Find) 
{
   std::vector<int> v{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   EXPECT_EQ(1, std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 1));
   EXPECT_EQ(6, std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 6));
   EXPECT_EQ(2, std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 2));
   EXPECT_EQ(10, std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 10));
}

TEST(MaxTest, Max)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(3, std::max(1, 3));
    EXPECT_EQ(11, std::max(11, 4));
    EXPECT_EQ(2, std::max(7, 1));
    EXPECT_EQ(9, std::max(9, 3));
    EXPECT_EQ(3, std::max(2, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, да. Вызывают сомнение только эти две строки, неужели не падают?

```
EXPECT_EQ(2, std::max(7, 1));
EXPECT_EQ(3, std::max(2, 4));
```

Но тестировать стандартные функции не нужно, гораздо интереснее тестировать свой собственный код. Это иногда не так просто, как может показаться. Так что пробуйте писать тесты к своему коду. Можете начать с похожих методов, которые являются чистыми функциями (такие методы легче всего тестировать).